# Python 2.6 to 2.5 cheat sheet

Tags: python, python-2.6, python-2.5, backport

I've written my code to target Python 2.6.5, but I now need to run it on a cluster that only has 2.5.4, something that wasn't on the horizon when I wrote the code. Backporting the code to 2.5 shouldn't be too hard, but I was wondering if there was either a cheat-sheet or an automated tool that would help me with this. For some things, like the `with` statement, the right `__future__` imports will do the trick, but not for some other things.

Comment: I dunno why I thought it was 2.5.38, it's actually 2.5.4. Edited now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you read the [What's New in Python 2.6](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.6.html) document?  It describes the 2.5->2.6 direction, but you should be able to figure out the reverse from it.

As far as I know, there are no automated tools for 2.6 to 2.5.  The only tool I know of is the 2to3 app for going to Python 3.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried [pyqver](http://github.com/ghewgill/pyqver)? It will tell you which is the minimum version of Python required by your code

I hope it helps